# How can I retrieve Facebook User Info without Access Token

Tags: facebook

I found a good tutorial for building Facebook membership Authentication website which demo file is here > http://niftyandcrackerjack.com/sites/default/files/Test.zip

I wonder this example does not use access token to retrieve Facebook User Info. It use classes inherits from the masterpage. As I am new to ASP.NET, I don't know how to retrieve Facebook user info. Can someone give me and suggestion or explain...... Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

My finding so far indicate that basic information cannot be accessed unless one has either 'userid' or 'username' as in this post.

If one has to try and fetch basic information using following url, then access_token is needed

http://graph.facebook.com/me

Comment: _Of course_ with `/me` an access token is needed – otherwise there’s no way of telling for the API who “me” is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Perform an HTTP GET to `https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}` or HTTP GET to `https://graph.facebook.com/{username}`

Examples: Click the link below to see the JSON response.

https://graph.facebook.com/4

https://graph.facebook.com/zuck

Pretty cool, eh?  And no token needed to get at this public info.

You can get more info on this here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Comment: Nope. "An access token is required to request this resource."